# Find the start of a cache line for a Java byte array

Tags: java, performance, bloom-filter

For a high performance blocked bloom filter, I would like to align data to cache lines. (I know it's easier to do such tricks in C, but I would like to use Java.)

I do have a solution, but I'm not sure if it's correct, or if there is a better way. My solution tries to find the start of the cache line using the following algorithm:

- for each possible offset o (0..63; I assume cache line length of 64)
- start a thread that reads from data[o] and writes that to data[o + 8]
- in the main thread, write '1' to data[o], and wait until that ends up in data[o + 8] (so wait for the other thread)
- repeat that

Then, measure how fast this was, basically how many increments for a loop of 1 million (in each thread). My logic is, it is slower if the data is in a different cache line.

Here my code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        int size = (int) (1000 + Math.random() * 1000);
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        int cacheLineOffset = getCacheLineOffset(data);
        System.out.println("offset: " + cacheLineOffset);
    }
}

private static int getCacheLineOffset(byte[] data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x = tryGetCacheLineOffset(data, i + 3);
        if (x != -1) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Cache line start not found");
    return 0;
}

private static int tryGetCacheLineOffset(byte[] data, int testCount) {
    // assume synchronization between two threads is faster(?)
    // if each thread works on the same cache line
    int[] counters = new int[64];
    int testOffset = 8;
    for (int test = 0; test < testCount; test++) {
        for (int offset = 0; offset < 64; offset++) {
            final int o = offset;
            final Semaphore sema = new Semaphore(0);
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sema.acquire();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                        data[o + testOffset] = data[o];
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            sema.release();
            data[o] = 1;
            int counter = 0;
            byte waitfor = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                byte x = data[o + testOffset];
                if (x == waitfor) {
                    data[o]++;
                    counter++;
                    waitfor++;
                }
            }
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            counters[offset] += counter;
        }
    }
    Arrays.fill(data, 0, testOffset + 64, (byte) 0);
    int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE, high = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        // average of 3
        int avg3 = (counters[(i - 1 + 64) % 64] + counters[i] + counters[(i + 1) % 64]) / 3;
        low = Math.min(low, avg3);
        high = Math.max(high, avg3);
    }
    if (low * 1.1 > high) {
        // no significant difference between low and high
        return -1;
    }
    int lowCount = 0;
    boolean[] isLow = new boolean[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (counters[i] < (low + high) / 2) {
            isLow[i] = true;
            lowCount++;
        }
    }
    if (lowCount != 8) {
        // unclear
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if (isLow[(i - 1 + 64) % 64] && !isLow[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It prints (example):

```
offset: 16
offset: 24
offset: 0
offset: 40
offset: 40
offset: 8
offset: 24
offset: 40
...
```

So arrays in Java seems to be aligned to 8 bytes.

Comment: Some ideas: You know that the GC can move objects... so your perfectly aligned array may get misaligned later. I'd try `ByteBuffer`; I guess, a direct one gets aligned a lot (to a page boundary). Unsafe can give you the address and with JNI, you can get an array pinned.

Comment: @maaartinus you are right. I will try ByteBuffer.allocateDirect. According to my tests, those seem to be always cache line aligned. I will test if those are as fast as long arrays.

Comment: @maaartinus (I didn't finish my tests, but) if you convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Nice! Feel free to add more details... my answer is pretty short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the GC can move objects... so your perfectly aligned array may get misaligned later.

I'd try `ByteBuffer`; I guess, a direct one gets aligned a lot (to a page boundary).

Unsafe can give you the address and with JNI, you can get an array pinned.

Comment: You want to say, that array can get rearanged by the GC?

Comment: Yes, according to the spec and documentation it's possible ("compacting collector"). But I don't think very large arrays are moved that often. It would require a "stop the world"

Answer (score 2):

First things first - *everything* in java is 8 bytes aligned, not arrays only. There's a tool for that [Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/), that you can play with. Small-ish thing here (unrelated, but related) - in `java-9` `String`(s) internally are stored as `byte[]` to shrink their space for `LATIN-1` ones, because everything is 8-bytes aligned there was an addition of a field `coder` (`byte`) *without* making any instance of the string bigger - there was a gap big enough to fit that byte.

Your entire idea that objects that are aligned will be faster to access is right. That is much much more visible when multiple threads try to access that data, also known as `false-sharing` (but I bet you knew that). Btw here, there are methods in `Unsafe` that will show you object addresses, but since `GC` can move these around, this becomes useless for your requirement.

You would [not be the first one](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/false-sharing.html) that tries to overcome this. Unfortunately if you read that blog entry - you will see that even very experienced developers (which I admire) fail at this. A VM is notoriously smart to remove checks and code that you might think is needed somewhere, especially when `JIT` `C2` kicks in.

What you are really looking for is:

```
jdk.internal.vm.annotation.Contended
```

annotation. This is the *only* way that will guarantee cache line alignment. If you really want to read about all other "tricks" that could be done, than [Alekesy Shipilev's](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/3769055ad883/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_22_FalseSharing.java) examples are the ones you are looking for.